# Getting data from JSON file using AJAX. How to shorten the code using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How can I shorten the code using jQuery? Instead of selecting each element manually, maybe using a separate function to create `<li>` elements could be an idea?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'choosePizza.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(choosePizzaData) {
    choosePizzaHTML(choosePizzaData);
  }
});

function choosePizzaHTML(choosePizzaInData) {
  var boxar = $('.box1_data');
  var text = "";

  /*Selecting each parameter manually and get the value from the json file and place them in a list. Is there a way to shorten this? Without having to select it manually*/

  $(choosePizzaInData[0]).each(function(index, value) {
    text += '<li>' + value.botten[0] + '</li>';
    text += '<li>' + value.botten[1] + '</li>';
  });
  boxar.html(text);

  var box2 = $('.box2_data');
  var text = "";
  $(choosePizzaInData[1]).each(function(index, value) {
    text += '<li>' + value.topping[0] + '</li>';
    text += '<li>' + value.topping[1] + '</li>';
    text += '<li>' + value.topping[2] + '</li>';
  });
  box2.html(text);
}
```

Example JSON:

```
[ { "botten": ["Krispig", "tunn"] }, { "topping": ["kött", "kyckling", "tomat"] }, { "extra": ["Fanta", "Coca cola", "Sprite"] } ]
```

Comment: It would help to see the JSON response from the AJAX request here. Although, there doesn't appear to be much wrong with your logic.

Comment: you can use 
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ){

Comment: It prints out what i want, but there are more columns i need to print with more values, its gonna get pretty long so maybe using a function or something could shorten the code? 
Thanks

Comment: We can't offer you any 'function' logic without knowing 1) what the data structure is 2) what the output should look like. You've told us neither of those things.

Comment: I would like to print out some values "topping" etc.  in 3 separate lists.
The data is stored in a separate JSON file.

[
    {
        "botten": ["Krispig", "tunn"]
    },
    
    {
        "topping": ["kött", "kyckling", "tomat"]
    
    },
    {
        "extra": ["Fanta", "Coca cola", "Sprite"]
    
    }
]

Comment: The problem is that i now have to select each manually, and would like to know if there is a way to shorten this code.
Sorry for not providing sufficient information.

Comment: @GarGouL please click the `edit` link under the tags on your question, and add that JSON to the question, rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the code even without JQuery with the use of map method:

```
text = choosePizzaInData[0].botten.map(function(v) { 
           return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
       }).join('');

text = choosePizzaInData[1].topping.map(function(v) { 
           return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
       }).join('');
```